# Setting up Managed Switch as Unmanage

Tags: networking, switch

New to Networking,
Currently, I have Cisco sg 300 POE Manage Switch and want to make this switch as unmanaged. Can I make this switch as unmanaged just by plug and play or I need to set it up by Configuration to make it happen as Unmanaged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to accomplish, but if you just want to use the switch as is out of the box then simply plug it in and start connecting devices to it. Just make sure you don't have a device with the same ip address as the default ip address of the switch.

If you want to use it as an unmanaged switch then... don't manage it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to change the default password first, at least. Otherwise your switch is eventually managed by someone else.

One option is to leave the management VLAN open on just one port and use all the other ports on a separate VLAN without touching any other configuration, just like they were unmanaged ports. That'll also prevent the IP conflict mentioned in joeqwerty's answer.